# Code Refactoring issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have game ready and now I am trying to refactor code. I have derived Spider class from CCNode and used targeted delegate method CCTargetedTouchDelegate.

```
@interface Spider : CCNode<CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
    CCSprite* spiderSprite;
    NSString * spiderKilled;
    int killed;
    AppDelegate *del;
}

+(id) spiderWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode;
-(id) initWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode;

@end
```

On Touch spider should be killed and here goes the code:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint tch = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:tch];

    // Check if this touch is on the Spider's sprite.
    BOOL isTouchHandled = CGRectContainsPoint([spiderSprite boundingBox], touchLocation);

    if (isTouchHandled)
    {
        j = j + 1;
        killed ++;
        [del setKilledScore:j];
        [self removeChild:spiderSprite cleanup:YES];
    }

    return isTouchHandled;
}
```

I am adding 10 spiders in GameScene layer using: -

```
 for(int i=0; i <10 ;i++){
      [Spider spiderWithParentNode:self];
    }
```

But, unfortunately I am not able to remove spiders and giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on this line: `[self removeChild:spiderSprite cleanup:YES];`

Please help me overcome this error.

Thanks

---

Update -- 
Spider Init code
    // Static autorelease initializer, mimics cocos2d's memory allocation scheme.
    +(id) spiderWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode
    {
        return [[[self alloc] initWithParentNode:parentNode] autorelease];
    }

```
-(id) initWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        [parentNode addChild:self];
        del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        spiderSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spider.png"];
        spiderSprite.position = CGPointMake(CCRANDOM_0_1() * screenSize.width, CCRANDOM_0_1() * screenSize.height);
        [self addChild:spiderSprite];

        // Manually add this class as receiver of targeted touch events.
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where spiderSprite is initialized and added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: I have added the spider init code at the end..

Answer (score 0):

If you manually add the class to the CCTouchDispatcher list, you should remove it from there after you're done using it.